# JetBrains Rider and ASP.Net web site project

Tags: c#, asp.net, rider

I have a solution with an ASP.Net web site project which I develop using the Visual Studio. 
I've tried to load the solution with the Rider (versions 2017.1.1 and 2017.2 EAP).
 
When solution opens I see that projects are loading but the loading process doesn't finish. I've been waiting for several hours.
In June or July I tried earlier Rider EAP versions of the on the solution and it worked.
Does the rider have any problems with support of web site projects?

Comment: Could you send us all logs, it looks like a major bug... Show -> Show logs in... -> zip all logs and create an issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/rider

Comment: For that kind of specific issue, you can only reach out to JetBrains by reporting a bug.

Comment: Thank you. I've created an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-9235).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you've had the same a I did before. I was discussing the issue with JB and support them with some details of my project.

After a while it seems like new Rider 2017.3 eap fixes this issue with neverending loading.

JetBrains Rider 2017.3 EAP
Build #RD-173.3994.576, built on December 13, 2017

Unfortunately it's still not possible to run web side project as easy as in VS.

This is still in development.